# Determining average duration between input and output (example - CoVID-19 sickness)

Tags: curve-fitting, lognormal-distribution

Let us assume there are given two sets on data, input and output of a process. For an example, daily number of infected people by CoVID-19 and daily number of resolved cases, be it death or healing. We cannot know illness duration for individual patients, only daily cumulative numbers. Assuming that illness duration is described with log-normal distribution, how would one determine its parameters?

[image]

Comment: Well, I thought I had a solution, but it didn't work. Basically, tried to invert discrete convolution and see what do I get, but got something multi-modal which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Why would a multi-modal distribution be wrong?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus No reason whatsoever, except my biases. First, really didn't expected it. Second, there is no mention of it in published papers on dynamics of CoVID-19. Got the same thing with another method, taking it seriously.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus but if you think of it, it is really weird to have two distinct maxima in the response function. I need to look at more countries to see if this is function of the illness itself or maybe result of treatment in specific healthcare system. And, of course, I need to check out my calculation method.

Comment: I do not find the double peak so strange. If these are reports about covid-19 cases then you should keep in mind that they are very biased and noisy. Also the function that describes the time untill being resolved may be non constant in time. Or the bimodal behaviour is in the cases and not in the time until being resolved (and then you have a multiple waves of cases, but you registered only a single one due to inaccurate measurements). Any way, there are lots of ways that the data can deviate from your model.

Answer (score 1):

For given input and given parameters of the log normal distribution you can express the probability of the output. An exact calculation is difficult, but you could estimate it, either with simulation or with some approximate formula.

Then you can invert this relation and use it as a likelihood function which you can maximize to obtain a MLE, or when you have some priors you could obtain a posterior distribution of the parameters.

---

You could also try to match the mean and variance. (method of moments)